# Unable to bind DataGridView with DataTable/DataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

I am unable to bind `DataGridView` with `DataTable`/`DataReader` in `ado.net`. Also, I'm unable to show data `DataReader` data in `DataGridView`.

`DataGridView` is not showing any records.

How do I get `DataTable` from business layer to UI layer?

My code:

```
private void GetSMSSender() {
    try
    {
        string sqlcmd = "sp_getSmsSenders";
        SqlHelper sqlEvents = new SqlHelper();
        GridView1.DataSource = sqlEvents.ExecuteReader(sqlcmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}

public DataTable ExecuteReader(string sqlcmd) {
    DataTable table;
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(objCon.getConnectionString());
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(dr);
        return table;
     }
}
```

debugged the code.my dr results is below. kindly see
http://postimg.org/image/6p2wh185f/

Comment: create an object of the class and call the method which returns filled datatable and set the datasource of grid view to be the returned datatable in UI.

Comment: i have created object already in the above.

Comment: CommandType.Text is for text if you are calling Stored proc then use CommandType.StoredProcedure

Comment: you have to check if the code returns records first, then you look ahead for other problems such as page_load or viewstate problems

Comment: i made it stored procedure. still coming error.@learningNew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the problem you are facing and modified the code to use a `SqlDataAdapter` instead of `SqlDataReader`. This solved the problem:

```
private DataTable ExecuteReader(string sqlcmd)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(objCon.getConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(table);
        }
    }
    return table;

}
```

Comment: getting error/compilation error

Error 9 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'var' to 'string'@maurits

Comment: Sorry I have updated the code to work without using `var`

Comment: Can you see in the debugger which object is null in your UI layer?

Comment: but y cant we use commandreader. i think sqldataadapter decrease performance...@maurits

Comment: You can and I found out why you had a problem in your original code. The problem was related to closing the connection to soon. When you call the `table.Load(dr)` it will still need the connection to be open. 

If you move the `con.Close()` line two lines down (directly under the `table.Load(dr)`) it will work properly. Unfortunately I missed this at first. You will still need to make sure you set the `CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` as mentioned in my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

After taking a closer look there are two problems in your code:

**First problem:**

It looks like you want to call a stored procedure. However you have set your `CommandType` to Text. Meaning ADO.NET expects to execute a normal query instead of executing a stored procedure. There are two ways on solving this.

The first (and preferred way) is to set your `CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` like show in the code below:

```
con = new SqlConnection(objCon.getConnectionString());
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
table = new DataTable();
table.Load(dr);
con.Close();
return table;
```

The other way is to send a text query to the SQL server telling it to execute the stored procedure (in this case you leave the `CommandType` set to `CommandType.Text`):

`string sqlcmd = "EXEC sp_GetSmsSenders";`

**Second problem:**

You close the connection to early. The SqlDataReader need the connection open while it does it's magic. To solve this problem simple move the line `con.Close()` two lines down just below the line `table.Load(dr)` like so:

```
con.Open();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
table = new DataTable();
table.Load(dr);
con.Close();
```

Comment: i made it  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
but still not coming records in  grid. kindly see this image

http://postimg.org/image/6p2wh185f/

Answer (score 0):

Try this methods:

```
      public static DataSet ToDateSet(IDataReader reader)
        {
            var ds = new DataSet();

            do
            {

                var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                var dt = new DataTable(schema.TableName);

                for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < reader.FieldCount; columnIndex++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(schema.Rows[columnIndex][0].ToString(), (Type)schema.Rows[columnIndex][2]));
                }

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

                    reader.GetValues(values);

                    dt.Rows.Add(values);
                }

                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            } while (reader.NextResult());

            return ds;
        }

public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string connectionString,string cmdText,CommandType cmdType) { 

      var  con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      var  cmd = new SqlCommand(conn,sqlcmd);

        cmd.CommandType = cmdType; 
        con.Open();

     return cmd.ExecuteReader();    
}

private void DoSMSSender() { 
var reader=ExecuteReader(objCon.getConnectionString(),"EXEC sp_GetSmsSenders",CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var ds=ToDateSet(reader);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

}
```

Your problems is Connection cosing & Command type.
I simple wrote here!